# complex objects, within a collection / arrays. create an easy key- indexing approach

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, collections, data-management

i have created a custom object that it's job is to give some more information on the data it holds...

so besides data, i have an object that is a base / "myObject" for all data i "deal" with, it will always carry its declaration name e.g Name, i also intend to have it categories itself (this is not my invention, that's kinda what namespaces are in .net c# where i feel more comfortable programming)

so this is the cause, ...some established form of common properties / values to all program data dealt with.

the problem is when it's within a collection /seq / set /array 
i would like to be able to index it (in `c#` i heavily use `indexer`s and enums)
where i could create an object and access it's data via it's a key.

```
                      //pName        pVal (usually a data/json object could be anything)
var someRprop = Rprp("HomePhone" , { dtT: "string", dt: "0044-01...", cat "cusDat", division: "portal"; catId: 32}) 

function Rprp(parName, parVal) {
        var cretdprp = {
            pName:pPropName,
            pVal: pVal,
            pValAsint: parseInt(this.pVal)

        };
    return cretdprp;
}
```

now if i need to create an indexed by key collection i can't understand how i could create a matching collection-object to be able to access it via the property name.

so for instance, in the main object properties of any program i create, i have one such as "datatypes" :

```
//btw it has "nice" combination of Parentheses
function ProgMan(){
        var Core = { 
                     //          here is where it's get little complicated for my current level of javascript
                     DataTypes: [
                                 { 
                                  DateTime : Rprp("DateTime", {LenType :shortName, mxL: 35, isNumeric: false//... etc})
                                 }
                     ],
                     DataNcnsts: { I32 : "int", str: "string", Dt : "DateTime" },
                     HelmFactory : { }

     };
return Core;
}
```

**Edit** added context of usage

```
   TabularsWHRM: function () {
                            var rtWH = {
                                            DTNDataTypes: function () {

                                                    var rtarr = new Array();
                                                    rtarr =[ Rprp("DateTime", {dateTime: this.DbLengts.pVal.vals.NameShort}),Rprp("int32", {Int32 : this.DbLengts.pVal.vals.NameShort }), Rprp("bool", { Boolean : this.DbLengts.pVal.vals.NameShort }), Rprp("objct", { Object: undefined }), Rprp("csvString", { CsvString: this.DbLengts.pVal.vals.csvString }), Rprp("string", { String: this.DbLengts.pVal.vals.string }), Rprp("Json", { Json: undefined }), Rprp("FileObj", { File: this.DbLengts.pVal.vals.NameShort })];
                                                    var tk = rtarr["DateTime"];
                                                    console.log("MyNamedkey >" + key.pName + " has Length value " + rtarr[key].pVal);
                                                    for (var key in rtarr) {

                                                        console.log("key " + key.pName + " has value " + rtarr[key].pVal.dateTime);
                                                        if (key == this.DTNDataTypes.dateTime) {
                                                    //dateTime: "DateTime", int32: "Int32", bool : "Boolean", objct: "Object",csvString: "CsvString", string : "String", Json: "Json", aFileObj: "File"}
                                                        }
                                                }
                                                return rtarr;
                                            },
                                            DbLengts: Rprp ("DbLengts",
                                            {
                                                vals : {
                                                                        NameShort: 25,
                                                                        Name: 50, NameLong: 150,
                                                                        PathIO: 450, ShortDesc: 150, Desc: 450,
                                                                        CommentsL1: 1000, CommentsL2: 2000, Text: 4000
                                                                        ,generate: function (pDTNDataTypes){
                                                                        var s = pDTNDataTypes;
                                                                        var rtIval = -1;
                                                                            switch (s) {
                                                                                case this.names.nameShort : rtIval = this.NameShort;
                                                                                case this.names.name: rtIval = this.Name;
                                                                                case this.names.nameLong: rtIval = this.NameLong;
                                                                                case this.names.pathIO: rtIval = this.PathIO;
                                                                                case this.names.shortDesc: rtIval = this.ShortDesc;
                                                                                case this.names.desc: rtIval = this.Desc;
                                                                                case this.names.commentsL1: rtIval = this.CommentsL1;
                                                                                case this.names.commentsL2: rtIval = this.CommentsL2;
                                                                                case this.names.text: rtIval = this.Text;

                                                                                default: rtIval = 800;
                                                                                break;

                                                                            }
                                                                          return  parseInt(rtIval);
                                                                        }

                                                        },
                                                names : 
                                                { 
                                                  nameShort : "NameShort", name : "Name", nameLong : "NameLong", pathIO : "PathIO", shortDesc : "ShortDesc", desc : "Desc", commentsL1 : "CommentsL1", commentsL2 : "CommentsL2", text : "Text"
                                                }
                                            })



                            };
                        return rtWH;
       },
```

Comment: I'm a bit fuzzy on what exactly you need here, but is there a reason JavaScript's built-in `Set` class doesn't fulfill your needs? It sounds like you just need a simple collection of key-value pairs?

Comment: @JCD  did u take into account the `Rprp(parName , parVal)` ,  with function(s) such as `ToInt()` , my custom object as the element in the set?

Comment: I don't understand the question, sorry.

Comment: @JCD i will add my try so it'll be easier please try to help then . thanks

Comment: @JCD i guess now it's easier to see in what context it resides in, i m trying to access element via it's name but the element is a `Rprop` not a basic js `{}`

Comment: Sorry I misspoke earlier, I was thinking of the `Map` class, not `Set`. `Map` is very powerful because anything can be used as a key, it's very efficient, and you can query the size. If you need a key-value pair collection, you should look into it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: @JCD do you do `api`s too ?  like instead of programming and then render `<input type= 'text' ...>` then another html elm - input for another or did you ever think an do (had the time for) something like `var FrmclientReqOrderDetails = formCreate("frmClientReq...." ,"text", "name", "text", "orderid",x,y, z)` then vualla ...a form is renderd via input which assiged with - take name fld so (inside formCreate):  `var input1 = new MyPracticalHelms_inputT(Length_name, dir_rtl, Aln_Lft)` so it also knows maxlen from Lengh object ...etc'...etc' what say you ?

Comment: and thanks for pointing out the `Map` i will intergrate it within my code first chance i will see fits. for now i left my `Rprp` out (before your last comment) and used no fancy  `var DtTypsBNK =    {

                                "bit": { DataT:  this.names.Bit, Len: 1 },......};`